# How to copy files from one bucket to another bucket WITH SAME ACL in same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I copied files from one bucket to another bucket using AWS CLI.
It worked great.

```
aws s3 sync s3://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME s3://NEW_BUCKET_NAME
```

But the thing is objects' ACL weren't copied.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/terminator9999/aws-s3-bucket-copy/,https://github.com/cobbzilla/s3s3mirror/tree/2.1-stable these are the scripts that cna help you to solve your propose or try looking in the include/exlude option of sync command

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I found the solution:

```
aws s3 cp s3://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME s3://NEW_BUCKET_NAME --recusive --acl public-read
```

Here `--acl public-read` can be changed depending on permissions.